# Error "ng serve" on cmd

Tags: javascript, angular, npm

when i type at cmd "ng serve" for running angular2 it appears errors:

"unknown browser query basedir=$(dirname $(echo $0 | sed -e s,\,/,g))"

> Unknown browser query `basedir=$(dirname "$(echo "$0" | sed -e 's,\\,/,g')")`
>       BrowserslistError: Unknown browser query `basedir=$(dirname "$(echo "$0" | sed -
>       e 's,\\,/,g')")`
>       at error (D:\angular_node\aaa\node_modules\browserslist\index.js:37:11)
>       at D:\angular_node\aaa\node_modules\browserslist\index.js:215:9
>       at Array.forEach (native)
>       at browserslist (D:\angular_node\aaa\node_modules\browserslist\index.js:192:
>       13)
>       at cleanBrowsersList (D:\angular_node\aaa\node_modules\caniuse-api\dist\util
>       s.js:56:59)
>       at setBrowserScope (D:\angular_node\aaa\node_modules\caniuse-api\dist\index.
>       js:30:43)
>       at Object. (D:\angular_node\aaa\node_modules\caniuse-api\dist\ind
>       ex.js:92:1)
>       at Module._compile (module.js:570:32)
>       at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:579:10)
>       at Module.load (module.js:487:32)
>       at tryModuleLoad (module.js:446:12)
>       at Function.Module._load (module.js:438:3)
>       at Module.require (module.js:497:17)
>       at require (internal/module.js:20:19)
>       at Object. (D:\angular_node\aaa\node_modules\postcss-merge-rules\
>       dist\lib\ensureCompatibility.js:7:19)
>       at Module._compile (module.js:570:32)
>       at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:579:10)
>       at Module.load (module.js:487:32)
>       at tryModuleLoad (module.js:446:12)
>       at Function.Module._load (module.js:438:3)
>       at Module.require (module.js:497:17)
>       at require (internal/module.js:20:19)
>       at Object. (D:\angular_node\aaa\node_modules\postcss-merge-rules\
>       dist\index.js:23:28)
>       at Module._compile (module.js:570:32)
>       at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:579:10)
>       at Module.load (module.js:487:32)
>       at tryModuleLoad (module.js:446:12)
>       at Function.Module._load (module.js:438:3)
>       at Module.require (module.js:497:17)
>       at require (internal/module.js:20:19)
>       at Object. (D:\angular_node\aaa\node_modules\cssnano\dist\index.j
>       s:113:26)
>       at Module._compile (module.js:570:32)
>       at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:579:10)
>       at Module.load (module.js:487:32)
>       at tryModuleLoad (module.js:446:12)
>       at Function.Module._load (module.js:438:3)
>       at Module.require (module.js:497:17)
>       at require (internal/module.js:20:19)
>       at Object. (D:\angular_node\aaa\node_modules\angular-cli\models\w
>       ebpack-configs\styles.js:6:15)
>       at Module._compile (module.js:570:32)
>       at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:579:10)
>       at Module.load (module.js:487:32)
>       at tryModuleLoad (module.js:446:12)
>       at Function.Module._load (module.js:438:3)
>       at Module.require (module.js:497:17)
>       at require (internal/module.js:20:19)
>       at Object. (D:\angular_node\aaa\node_modules\angular-cli\models\w
>       ebpack-configs\index.js:8:10)
>       at Module._compile (module.js:570:32)
>       at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:579:10)
>       at Module.load (module.js:487:32)
>       at tryModuleLoad (module.js:446:12)
>       at Function.Module._load (module.js:438:3)
>       at Module.require (module.js:497:17)
>       at require (internal/module.js:20:19)
>       at Object. (D:\angular_node\aaa\node_modules\angular-cli\models\w
>       ebpack-config.js:4:25)
>       at Module._compile (module.js:570:32)
>       at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:579:10)
>       at Module.load (module.js:487:32)
>       at tryModuleLoad (module.js:446:12)
>       at Function.Module._load (module.js:438:3)
>       at Module.require (module.js:497:17)
>       at require (internal/module.js:20:19)
>       at Object. (D:\angular_node\aaa\node_modules\angular-cli\tasks\se
>       rve.js:11:24)
>       at Module._compile (module.js:570:32)
>       at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:579:10)
>       at Module.load (module.js:487:32)
>       at tryModuleLoad (module.js:446:12)
>       at Function.Module._load (module.js:438:3)
>       at Module.require (module.js:497:17)
>       at require (internal/module.js:20:19)
>       at Object. (D:\angular_node\aaa\node_modules\angular-cli\commands
>       \serve.run.js:6:15)
>       at Module._compile (module.js:570:32)
>       at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:579:10)
>       at Module.load (module.js:487:32)
>       at tryModuleLoad (module.js:446:12)
>       at Function.Module._load (module.js:438:3)
>       at Module.require (module.js:497:17)
>       at require (internal/module.js:20:19)
>       at Class.run (D:\angular_node\aaa\node_modules\angular-cli\commands\serve.js
>       :67:16)
>       at Class. (D:\angular_node\aaa\node_modules\angular-cli\ember-cli
>       \lib\models\command.js:134:17)
>       at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:103:7)

So I've searched all around the Google Globe, but found nothing.
anyone can tell me how to fix it??? thanks anyway...
note: i run on windows 8 32 bit

Angular-cli.json

```js
{
  "project": {
    "version": "1.0.0-beta.28.3",
    "name": "testing"
  },
  "apps": [
    {
      "root": "src",
      "outDir": "dist",
      "assets": [
        "assets",
        "favicon.ico"
      ],
      "index": "index.html",
      "main": "main.ts",
      "polyfills": "polyfills.ts",
      "test": "test.ts",
      "tsconfig": "tsconfig.json",
      "prefix": "app",
      "styles": [
        "styles.css"
      ],
      "scripts": [],
      "environments": {
        "source": "environments/environment.ts",
        "dev": "environments/environment.ts",
        "prod": "environments/environment.prod.ts"
      }
    }
  ],
  "e2e": {
    "protractor": {
      "config": "./protractor.conf.js"
    }
  },
  "lint": [
    {
      "files": "src/**/*.ts",
      "project": "src/tsconfig.json"
    },
    {
      "files": "e2e/**/*.ts",
      "project": "e2e/tsconfig.json"
    }
  ],
  "test": {
    "karma": {
      "config": "./karma.conf.js"
    }
  },
  "defaults": {
    "styleExt": "css",
    "prefixInterfaces": false,
    "inline": {
      "style": false,
      "template": false
    },
    "spec": {
      "class": false,
      "component": true,
      "directive": true,
      "module": false,
      "pipe": true,
      "service": true
    }
  }
}
```

package.json

```js
{
  "name": "testing",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "license": "MIT",
  "angular-cli": {},
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "test": "ng test",
    "pree2e": "webdriver-manager update --standalone false --gecko false",
    "e2e": "protractor"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/common": "^2.3.1",
    "@angular/compiler": "^2.3.1",
    "@angular/core": "^2.3.1",
    "@angular/forms": "^2.3.1",
    "@angular/http": "^2.3.1",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^2.3.1",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^2.3.1",
    "@angular/router": "^3.3.1",
    "core-js": "^2.4.1",
    "rxjs": "^5.0.1",
    "ts-helpers": "^1.1.1",
    "zone.js": "^0.7.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^2.3.1",
    "@types/jasmine": "2.5.38",
    "@types/node": "^6.0.42",
    "angular-cli": "1.0.0-beta.28.3",
    "codelyzer": "~2.0.0-beta.1",
    "jasmine-core": "2.5.2",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "2.5.0",
    "karma": "1.2.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "^2.0.0",
    "karma-cli": "^1.0.1",
    "karma-jasmine": "^1.0.2",
    "karma-remap-istanbul": "^0.2.1",
    "protractor": "~4.0.13",
    "ts-node": "1.2.1",
    "tslint": "^4.3.0",
    "typescript": "~2.0.3"
  }
}
```

Comment: Show me your `package.json` and `angular-cli.json` files.

Comment: i have added it in my question

Answer (score 6):

Just delete the "browserlist" (text file) from project directory, and also delete "browserlist.cmd" file.
(it worked for me)

Answer (score 2):

See:
https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/3938#issuecomment-272633128

(Changing filename "browserlist" to "00_browserslist" in your project folder, fixed it for me)

Answer (score 2):

I was facing same issue on windows 10 with node version 10.0.0 and angular cli version 1.7.4. Now removed browserlists file and browserslist.cmd in project directory. It works for me :).